# explain split('e') in python for the string "wheel steep string"

Tags: python

Iam learner of python. while working with below ex for python

> a='wheel steep street'
>
> a.split('e')
>
> o/p :['wh', '', 'l st', '', 'p str', '', 't']

need explanation about the working of split in the above code.
while splitting based on 'e', 
    It should remove 'e' and nothing should be printed but
    the output was whitespace('') for the character 'e' in the input.

Got confused about two white spaces("") in the output. Explanation about the above functionality will clear my doubt.

Answer (score 5):

If there was one 'e' in each of those three words, the output would be:

```
['wh', 'l st', 'p str', 't']
```

However, because there are two 'e's, there is an empty string `''` between them, and thats why you see it in the output.

For example, if you split `wheeel` on `e`, you will see two empty strings in the output because there is an empty string between the first and second 'e' and the second and third 'e'.

Answer (score 3):

From the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If a separator is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2']).

In your case, the separator is 'e' so consecutive ones are not grouped together and hence the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `str.split` is giving you the substrings *between* your separator strings. Let's break out just the word "wheel" to see what that looks like

```
w h e e l
```

Since we're looking at substrings *between* separators, let's draw some lines where that would go, one at a time

```
w h e e l
    ^
```

Splitting on the first `e` ends up with

```
w h        e l
```

Repeating the process:

```
w h        e l
           ^
```

`wh` doesn't change, but `el` splits on the e, leaving:

```
w h        _ l
```

the underscore there isn't an underscore, it's standing in for *nothing*. In Python that's an empty string. Similarly `'el'.split('e') == ['', 'l']`. There's only an empty string on the left side of the `e`, but we must respect it!

---

You could also visualize it thinking that we create partitions on either side of the separators. Let's use a nonsense word to be more clear

```
wheqxcel  ->  w h e q x c e l  ->  w h |e| q x c |e| l
```

pulling out those partitions looks like:

```
w h, q x c, l
```

But our real word doesn't have a `qxc` in between the two e's, so instead we have

```
wheel  ->  w h e e l  ->  w h |e| |e| l  ->  w h, ,l
```

Note the empty space there between the commas -- to represent that, we again need the empty string `''`.